# Drag and Drop without duplicate elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, drag-and-drop, pyqt, pyqt4

In PyQt4 with Python 3, how do I access the data being drag and dropped into a view/model?

### Background

I am building an interface with two `QListView`s.  I want to be able to drag an item from the first view and drop it into the second.  However, the list needs to remain unique, so dropping an item that's already in the list should do nothing.

### Problem

I've not been able to figure out how to access the data being dropped to verify that it's not already in the list.

### Research

I've found the `QAbstractItemModel` method `dropMimeData()`, which should return `True` to accept the dropped data, and `False` to reject it.  However, the drag and drop data is in a `QMimeData`, and it is of the type `application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist`.  Going off [the docs](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#decoding-imported-data), I tried to decode the data:

```
def dropMimeData(self, data, action, row, column, parent=None):
    stream = QtCore.QDataStream(data.data('application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist'))
    text = ''
    while not stream.atEnd():
        stream >> text
        print(text)
```

However, if I run this, I get

```
    stream >> text
ValueError: string of length 1 expected
```

If I set `text = 'a'`, then `a` just gets printed repeatedly.

I tried [this solution](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Handling%20Qt%27s%20internal%20item%20MIME%20type), but in Python 3 I cannot create a `QVariant` object (per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36847113/5031373)).

### Question

So how do I access the drag and drop data in PyQt?  Is there a way to decode the `QMimeData` stuff?  Or is there another way to check on what gets dropped?

### Update

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22774168/5031373).  My question is about accessing the data dropped in a `QAbstractItemView`/`QAbstractItemModel`, while that one is about basic dragging and dropping in PyQt.  The answer does not address how to get data from the mimetype `'application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist'`, nor does it show how to prevent duplicates in a `QAbstractItemModel`.

Comment: To understand you well, you have 2 QListView, let's say I drag an item from the first to the second, my question is the dragged item deleted from the first QListView?

Comment: @eyllanesc so what I want is if I drag an item from the first to the second, and the item is already in the second, I don't want the item to be added to the second

Comment: I understand that, for you to understand let's say that in the first QListView there are 5 items and in the second it is empty, if I drag an item to the second the first QListView will have at the end 4 or 5 items?

Comment: @eyllanesc I would want the first to have 5 items after the drag. Though it would be cool to see how to make the first one have 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out if you want to control your drag and drop behavior you need to set your own mime data.

You can encode the data you want to drag and drop any way you want.  I'm going to put the dragged items into a list and encode them as JSON because I'm lazy.

In the model for the source view, override `mimeTypes()` and `mimeData()`:

```
def mimeTypes(self):
    return ['text/json']

def mimeData(self, indexes):
    dragData = json.dumps([index.data() for index in indexes])
    mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()
    mimeData.setData('text/json', dragData)
    return mimeData
```

When someone grabs and drags an item/items from the list, Qt will call `mimeData()` to encode the items.  Here I get the item data for each index dragged, put it in a list, convert the list to a string via JSON, and add that JSON to the `QMimeData`.

In `mimeTypes()` I specify that the mime data will include JSON data.

---

In the model for the destination view, override `dropMimeData()`:

```
def dropMimeData(self, data, action, row, column, parent=None):
    dropData = json.loads(bytes(data.data('text/json')))
    for item in dropData:
        if item in self.stringList():
            self.removeRow(self.stringList().index(item))
    if row != -1:
        beginRow = row
    elif parent:
        beginRow = parent.row()
    else:
        beginRow = self.rowCount()
    self.insertRows(beginRow, len(dropData))
    for i, item in enumerate(dropData):
        self.setData(self.index(beginRow+i, 0), item)
    return True
```

In the first line I get the JSON data out of the `QMimeData` and decode it.  Then, in the `for` loop, I check to see if one of the items is already in the destination view.  If so, remove it.

After that the rest of the code determines where to add the new rows and inserts them.

---

More information is [in the docs](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/dnd.html), particularly the section about [adding new drag and drop types](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/dnd.html#adding-new-drag-and-drop-types).